# PyQt5 removing button

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

In the list_widget I have added a add button I also want to add a remove button which asks which item you  wants to remove and remove the chosen item. I was trying it to do but I didn't had any idea to do so .Also, please explain the solution I am a beginner with pyqt5 or I'd like to say absolute beginner.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, 
QListWidget, QListWidgetItem
import sys

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 200
        self.width = 500
        self.length = 500
        self.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.width, 
        self.length)
        self.setWindowTitle("Stock managment")

        self.iniTUI()

    def iniTUI(self):
        # buttons
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("+")
        self.b1.move(450, 100)
        self.b1.resize(50, 25)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.take_inputs)
        # This is the button I want to define.
        self.btn_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_minus.setText("-")
        self.btn_minus.move(0, 100)
        self.btn_minus.resize(50, 25)


        # list
        self.list_widget = QListWidget(self)

        self.list_widget.setGeometry(120, 100, 250, 300)

        self.item1 = QListWidgetItem("A")
        self.item2 = QListWidgetItem("B")
        self.item3 = QListWidgetItem("C")

        self.list_widget.addItem(self.item1)
        self.list_widget.addItem(self.item2)
        self.list_widget.addItem(self.item3)

        self.list_widget.setCurrentItem(self.item2)



    def take_inputs(self):
        self.name, self.done1 = 
 QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            self, 'Add Item to List', 'Enter The Item you want 
in 
            the list:')
        self.roll, self.done2 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(
            self, f'Quantity of {str(self.name)}', f'Enter 
            Quantity of {str(self.name)}:')

        if self.done1 and self.done2:
            self.item4 = QListWidgetItem(f"{str(self.name)}              
            Quantity{self.roll}")
            self.list_widget.addItem(self.item4)
            self.list_widget.setCurrentItem(self.item4)
               

    def clicked(self):
        self.label.setText("You clicked the button")
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.label.adjustSize()


def clicked():
    print("meow")
def window():
    apk = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()





    win.show()
    sys.exit(apk.exec_())
window()
```

Comment: Ignore that "def clicked(): print("meow")" I forgot to remove that.

Comment: then please [edit] your question and fix it, and while you're there please ensure that the syntax (including indentation) is correct. Consider that we must be able to copy, paste and run your code, possibly without any modification: try it on your own (on the post preview or the finalized question), if you cannot run it, then we couldn't even.

Comment: how to edit the question?

Comment: There's a link in my comment (as much as at the bottom of your question), have you tried to click it?!?

Answer (score 0):

The core issue here is the lack of separation of the *view* and the *data*. This makes it very hard to reason about how to work with graphical elements. You will almost certainly want to follow the Model View Controller design paradigm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
which offers a systematic way to handle this separation.

Once you do so, it immediately becomes very straight forward how to proceed with the question: You essentially just have a list, and you either want to add a thing to this list, or remove one based on a selection.

I include an example here which happens to use the built-in classes QStringListModel and QListView in Qt5, but it is simple to write your own more specialized widgets and models. They all just use a simple signal to emit to the view that it needs to refresh the active information.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class StuffViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Stock managment")

        # 1: Use layouts.
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        # 2: Don't needlessly store things in "self"
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        add = QPushButton("+")
        add.clicked.connect(self.add_new_stuff)
        vbox.addWidget(add)
        sub = QPushButton("-")
        sub.clicked.connect(self.remove_selected_stuff)
        vbox.addWidget(sub)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)

        # 3: Separate the view of the data from the data itself. Use Model-View-Controller design to achieve this.
        self.model = model
        self.stuffview = QListView()
        self.stuffview.setModel(self.model)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stuffview)

    def add_new_stuff(self):
        new_stuff, success = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Add stuff', 'Enter new stuff you want')
        if success:
            self.stuff.setStringList(self.stuff.stringList() + [new_stuff])

    def remove_selected_stuff(self):
        index = self.stuffview.currentIndex()
        all_stuff = self.stuff.stringList()
        del all_stuff[index.column()]
        self.stuff.setStringList(all_stuff)


def window():
    apk = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Data is clearly separated:
    # 4: Never enumerate variables! Use lists!
    stuff = QStringListModel(["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"])
    # The graphical components is just how you interface with the data with the user!
    win = StuffViewer(stuff)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(apk.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: I tried to add some stuff but the window disppears automatically when I clicks OK.

Comment: And the window also goes when I clicks minus.